# How to open external url in an internal WebView as default?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, default

So I have a WebView Application in Android Studio and I want that when I open an Url (from for example the Google App) it will open it in my App as default.
Here is a part of my code:

```
String url = "http://google.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

myBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
    myBrowser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            prefs.edit().putString("LastUrl", myBrowser.getUrl().toString()).commit();
            editText.setText(myBrowser.getUrl().toString());
            if (progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
            Pbar.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress == 100) {
                Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String URL) {
            if (URL != null && URL.startsWith("http://")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL)));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    myBrowser.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` with:

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String URL) {
          view.loadUrl(URL);
          return true;
        }
```

Comment: @B.Barthel: Feel free to explain, in detail, what "doesn't work for me" means.

Comment: I mean it doesn't open the url in my App its only opening the "open with..." tab but my App isn't listed...

Comment: @B.Barthel: Not every scenario is handled by `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. That is mostly for cases where the server issues a server-side redirect or where the user clicks on an ordinary link. If the site is doing anything else (e.g., Javascript stuff to open the URL), `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` will not be invoked.

Comment: what should I do if wanna open it from the Google App(Is JavaScript in this case involved?)?

Comment: @B.Barthel: If I had to guess, you will wind up having to rewrite the Web page. You would need to find some open source Web browsers that happen to use `WebView` as their foundation and see how they handle it.